# How to keep the next line \n from getting removed inside the email text?

Tags: javascript, extjs

All the \n are removed from the string when the text is put inside mail body .

```
 var valuess = Object.entries(feedBackText);

 valuess.forEach(function (key) {
    responseText = responseText.concat(' ' + key[0] + ':' + key[1] + '\n');
 });


 var parsedString = responseText.toString();
 window.location = "mailto:myid@gmail.com"+"?subject="+subjectmail+"&body=" + 
 parsedString;
```

Comment: Did you want to display '\n'?

Comment: No I want to display the next entry on new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following demonstrates how you can solve this using the built-in `encodeURIComponent` function:

```js
var parsedString = "text on the" + "\n" + "next line";

var link = "mailto:myid@gmail.com" + "?subject=Example&body=" +
  encodeURIComponent(parsedString);

console.log(link);
```

Comment: encodeURIComponent(parsedString); thank you it worked.